# Filesystem goes read only repeatidly

Tags: filesystems, ssd, fsck

My 4+yrs old Ubuntu 20.04.2 system on a Dell Latitude E7470 laptop and LITEON CV3-8D128 SSD is now switching to read-only after around 15 mins of use.

Symptoms are:

- all commands failing because of "input output errors"
- all icons disapearing
- nothing works basically
- sometime the desktop even disapear leaving with a console printing "systemd-journald: failed to write entry, ignoring: read-only file system".

What I tired:

- Rescue Mode: I can't `fsck -f /dev/sda6` because it is said to be "mounted" (or "active" when I try to umount)
- Live USB: I regularly don't even see the whole SSD aka `/dev/sda` in `parted` or even `lshw` so can't really `fsck`
- Dual Boot Windows: I never use this partition, but funily enough I could see the `sda6` partition from my Windows dual boot (and recover data).

Does it seems to be hardware failures ?
I can read the whole disk when booting Windows, but it may have write errors causing the system to switch into RO mode under Linux?

### Thanks a lot !

EDIT:

I just installed a new system (Ubuntu) on another partition nearby (located on the same SSD) and it seems to be OK: no problem for the last 24hrs while the other system fails in about half an hour.

---

SMART Values from `smartctl`:

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.8.0-43-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     LITEON CV3-8D128-11 SATA 128GB
Serial Number:    TW0WVD605508566U0BSM
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002303 100a14a70
Firmware Version: T87110B
User Capacity:    128,035,676,160 bytes [128 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      M.2
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS, ATA/ATAPI-7 T13/1532D revision 4a
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Apr  6 12:43:43 2021 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (   10) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x15) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Abort Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  11) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       11705
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       556
175 Program_Fail_Count_Chip 0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
176 Erase_Fail_Count_Chip   0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       334815
178 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Chip  0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
180 Unused_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot 0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       568
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       43
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       8
238 Unknown_Attribute       0x0003   088   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       12
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       27453
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       78550

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     11696         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         2         -

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

Comment: You've got hardware problems. Either the connector cable is loose or the SSD is dying. Usually SSDs go all at once so for now I'd suggest the other option

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How likely is it to get a loose "cable" in a laptop ? There's probably no "cable" tho but connectors ?! Note that the SSD is perfectly fine in read-only mode (i'm using it from a live USB atm)

Comment: Check the SSDs SMART values, should give you a rough lifespan indication

Comment: @Panki Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not really used with those numbers, I included it in the original post. Any clues?

Comment: Not an expert in SMART, but that does look rather bad. See the "Remaining" column near the bottom

Comment: Check `dmesg` for detailed error messages once this happens.

Comment: I just reinstalled the system on a partition nearby (located on the same SSD) and it seems OK. Not sure how it make sense.

Comment: @Panki the Remaining% at the bottom is the amount remaining of the self-test to completion, i.e. they have both finished. One was run when the disk was new; the other was run recently

Comment: If the SSD works "fine" in another machine then I re-suggest the connectors/cables in the original machine. SMART isn't flagging anything specific - the disk looks to be about 15 months old (maybe a little more) and there are no errors reported

Comment: @pltrdy Did it continue to work fine?! I am facing a similar problem and after a few days, the problems reappear.

Comment: Yes I used it without troubles for some months after that. I stopped using it just because I quit my job but it was ok